# Ember test using 3rd party (swag) helpers

Tags: ember.js, integration-testing, ember-cli

I am trying to write an integration test for an Ember-cli component, which uses [swag](https://github.com/elving/swag) helpers (specifically, `is`), but I can't figure out how to load the helpers so that they are available for the test. My test is about as simple as it gets, I just try to render the component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import { moduleForComponent, test } from 'ember-qunit';
import hbs from 'htmlbars-inline-precompile';


moduleForComponent('search-box', 'Integration | Component | search box', {
  integration: true
});

test('it renders', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(1);

  this.render(hbs`{{search-box}}`);

  assert.equal(this.$().text().trim(), '');
});
```

But it fails with

not

```
 ok 42 PhantomJS 2.0 - Integration | Component | search box: it renders
    ---
        actual: >
            null
        message: >
            Died on test #1     at test (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:1808:15)
                at http://localhost:7357/assets/client.js:14772:19
                at http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:150:34
                at tryFinally (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:30:21)
                at requireModule (http://localhost:7357/assets/vendor.js:148:15)
                at require (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:29:16)
                at loadModules (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:21:25)
                at load (http://localhost:7357/assets/test-loader.js:40:35)
                at http://localhost:7357/assets/test-support.js:5609:20: Assertion Failed: A helper named 'is' could not be found
        Log: >
    ...
```

I tried registering swag in the `start-app` helper using `Swag.registerHelpers()`, but I still get the error above, and a jshint error: `helpers/start-app.js: line 21, col 5, 'Swag' is not defined.`

The helpers load when I run the app, so how do I register them for the tests?

Comment: Ember version? You will either need to inject or use needs

Comment: Ember 1.13.  How would I use needs for a 3rd party helper?  Maybe I'm missing something obvious here...

Comment: Disregard, I had it wrong.